# Group repeating list objects with itertools.groupby()

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list, where I want to group the repeating objects into a single object in the new list. Basically, convert this:

```
s = ['0.352125', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0.241041', '0.313429', '1', '1']
```

to this: 
`s_new = ['0.352125', '4*1','8*0', '0.241041', '0.313429','2*1']`

I have tried `itertools.groupby()` function (python 2.7) as below:

```
from itertools import groupby
s_g = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(s)]
s_new = [', '.join('{}*{}'.format(sum(1 for _ in g), k) for k, g in groupby(s_g))]
```

As a result, I get:

`s_new = ["1*['0.352125'], 1*['1', '1', '1', '1'], 1*['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 1*['0.241041'], 1*['0.313429'], 1*['1', '1']"]`

Apparently, this is not the list format I'm trying to get. Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unnecessarily applied `groupby` twice and there's also no reason to use `str.join`.

You can use the following list comprehension instead:

```
['%s*' % len(l) * (len(l) > 1) + k for k, g in groupby(s) for l in (list(g),)]
```

Note that since Python 3.5, you can unpack each group into a list directly:

```
['%s*' % len(g) * (len(g) > 1) + k for k, [*g] in groupby(s)]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.